# Application to connect phone to PC and call other phones

Tags: 12.04, phone

Here is my dilemma. I will be building a local website that one of the things it will do is connect to a cellphone on the PC is run on and send a message to a client. The website part is not really the problem as much as a ubuntu tool that can do the following which will greatly help me in making the software at the end:

1. Connect a phone to the ubuntu PC
2. Have access to the phone so I can make calls from the PC using the phone or even send SMS.
3. Send a prerecorded message to the phone so it could call a client and tell them the prerecorded message.
4. Supports console line input.

Is there a software that can help me with this. It does not matter the phone since is hasn't been bought yet so it would depend on which type of phone is more compatible and then it will be bought. But basically is:

Ubuntu Client System -> Phone Connected to PC -> Call/SMS to Client via Phone to Phone

Comment: There are multiple pieces of software that can handle the SMS portion of your question (e.g. Gnokii can do this for a number of phones).  I haven't seen much for handling the audio of voice calls though (unless you're using a specialised voice card supported by software like asterisk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did that before with SMSLib (Java) with a lot of custom code to support my devices. Well, just SMS but you can do calls using AT commands. The problem for calls?: how to connect an audio output to the phone mic? that's a hardware hack I never did.

My recomendation: use a 3rd party service like http://m-lat.net or http://danaconnect.com